# PHP pdo - to many Connections

Tags: php, mysql, windows, pdo, tcp

I have an angular.js application with multiple views using PHP-PDO fetching data from a MySQL database.
Additionally there is a NodeJS application fetching data every 30 sec. from the same MySQL Database.

The angular and Node app run on a Windows Server. When starting the iis, tcp connections are increasing rapidly over 100, all with the Status "TIME_WAIT".

Is there a chance to reuse connections or reduce the waiting time for completely destroying a socket connection?

Comment: Do you close the db connection in each process when done fetching data?

Comment: What I do: "$db1 = new PDO();" and after all action is done: "$db1 = null;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting for every request is painfully slow. What you want is to use persistent connections and a connection pool, that way the connections can be recycled from one request to the next. This results in fewer connections and faster response times.

More information about this is in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Answer (score 0):

$db1 = null; sets your variable to null, but it doesn't inform the db server that the connection is not longer necessary so it can free up resources.

Before setting $db1 to null, close the connect

Read over the following pages for more detail
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php
and / or 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: You've got the right idea, but why are you linking to the wrong functions? This is a PDO question.

Comment: LOL ty, because I'm running a fever and missed the very clear "using php-pdo"?  upping YOUR answer, BTW...

Comment: TY, CEO is demoing the product I work on at a trade show today or I'd be home asleep LOL